# JNI: Does (*env)->NewObject create a Java object in the Java heap or not?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface

In the code below, `NewStringUTF` is calling `NewObject` under the hood.

My question is: *"Is the Java object created in the heap **right there**?"*

Then when I call `SetObjectField` just the **pointer** is copied. The object itself was already created in the heap much before `SetObjectField` is called, correct?

And my second question is: "Had I never called `SetObjectField`, when would it be garbage collected? Is there a way to delete this object from the heap so GC does not have to do it?"

```
#include "SimpleFile.h"

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_SimpleFile_set
  (JNIEnv * env, jobject jobj)
{
        jclass jcl;
        jfieldID jfid;
        jstring jstr;

        if(!(jcl=env->GetObjectClass(jobj)))
                return JNI_FALSE;

        jfid=env->GetFieldID(jcl,"fd","Ljava/lang/String;");
        if(!jfid)
                return JNI_FALSE;

        jstr=(jstring)(env->NewStringUTF("123")); // <==== NewObject
        env->SetObjectField(jcl,jfid,(jobject)jstr); // <==== Copying just the pointer, right?

        return JNI_TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right. Java object created in the heap right there.

Comment: @hellzone Thx! There is a follow up question I just added about GC

Comment: Since the C++ function appears to be called from Java, any local references created within the function (e.g. `jstr`) that you haven't explicitly deleted will be deleted when you return back to Java. And once that happens the object is a candidate for GC (assuming you haven't created any global references to the object).